# FileSystem Task using FileConnection in BIML

Tags: ssis, biml

How to add a FileSystem Task to Delete a file while providing FlatFileConnection name as SourceConnection?

below code doesn't work

```
<FileSystem Operation="DeleteFile" Name="FST-Delete File once It Is Loaded">
  <FileInput ConnectionName="FCM_LogIDMapping_LDW"></FileInput>
</FileSystem>
```

it gives error:

> Could not resolve reference to 'FCM_LogIDMapping_LDW' of type 'FileResource'. 'ConnectionName="FCM_LogIDMapping_LDW"' is invalid. Provide valid scoped name. Property FileConnection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with a Flat File as the input, you need to use `FlatFileInput`

```
<FileSystem 
    Operation="DeleteFile" 
    Name="FST-Delete File once It Is Loaded">
    <FlatFileInput ConnectionName="FCM_LogIDMapping_LDW" />
</FileSystem>
```

The `FileInput` is used for something like Excel